# TimeZone as a NIFI parameter for SQLExecute processor

Tags: apache-nifi

We are trying to connect oracle database through apache NIFI, but got an error "ORA-01882: timezone region not found"

There are tons of posts out there which talk about this error, many provide a solution to set time zone configuration in the bootstrap.conf file of NIFI. But since NIFI is a shared resource, we can't request to have a particular time zone configured.

Also, there were other solutions like editing the ojdbc6.jar to disable the timezone by using oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false but that did not help as well.

We were able to successfully establish the connection through sqopp command line by passing timeZone as a parameter( sqoop import -D oracle.sessionTimeZone=GMT.... ). Is there a way to achieve something similar through NIFI SQLExecute processor as well?

Comment: Not clear why you can't use `oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false`. You could set this as dbcpconnectionpool property...

Comment: I have added  oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false by editing ojdbc6.jar file under oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties. But that was not honored by NIFI server. How exactly can I set the JDBC property  in NIFI?

Comment: Add a dynamic property in dbcpconnectionpool.

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html

Comment: Ok since I am NIFI newbie, not sure about the dynamic properties, Sorry to ask this, but does that mean under the processor properties I add a new property like,  key as oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion and value as false?

Comment: It worked, thank you