# How to change timezone in Nifi?

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi, oracle12c, apache-nifi-registry

We are connecting Oracle database. When querying the date from the ExecuteSQL processor, the date column timezone is getting changed to UTC. How can we avoid this ?
Even I added oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false in controller service properties, but still it did not work.
We don't want to edit the bootstrap.conf for changing the timezone.  Is there a way to change timezone in Nifi ?

Further if my date column value in DB is having **2021-06-20 01:00:00** , when read in nifi the value changes to **2021-06-19 19:30:00**  where we can see 5:30 hours difference.
Same thing if I run it through java code, I am getting an exact date value as in DB.
Timezone in my system where Nifi is running is **Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)**

Comment: Sounds like It's a question to oracle jdbc driver. Nifi just using jdbc oracle driver to execute queries.

Comment: Hi @daggett , but as per this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066864/timezone-as-a-nifi-parameter-for-sqlexecute-processor) , its possible in nifi. But not working for me.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. I'm suggesting you to add oracle volunteers by adding `oracle` tag. Also please edit the question and add some details. Like: why do you think timezone has changed, what's the original value of timezone in db and that do you see in nifi, what is the region set on machine where you are running nifi, ... FYI: there are more properties about timezone in oracle jdbc driver https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html

Comment: okay have given further details.

Comment: It's the Avro reader that's changing it